# How to launch the "Basic Node.js Express 4 Application (Universal Windows)" without a debugger on Windows IoT?

Tags: node.js, windows, raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-10-iot-core

First post!

Would anyone know how to launch the Basic Node.js Express 4 Application (UWP) on my raspberry pi 2 without using visual studio debugger? This app will run fine if I launch via Visual Studio Remote Debugger, however if I launch either from the Windows IoT AppXManager or by setting the app as a start up app from PowerShell it fails with "Failed to start package..."

Operating System Version: Windows IoT
Device: Raspberry Pi 2
Sample Application: Basic Node.js Express 4 Application (UWP)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!

I made the RPI start in headless mode. Then added the Node.js app to the IoTStartUp startup list.